# Can you reuse a small WebGL buffer many times in one draw call?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Right now I am generating a large number of quads that all have the same vertices, and then passing in positions for the centers of those quads as an attribute, and a scale as a uniform.

For example, assume the following buffers

verts buffer:

```
-1,-1, -1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 1,-1, -1,1 // quad #1
-1,-1, -1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 1,-1, -1,1 // quad #2
-1,-1, -1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 1,-1, -1,1 // quad #3
-1,-1, -1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 1,-1, -1,1 // quad #3
```

position buffer:

```
10,10, 10,10, 10,10, 10,10, 10,10, 10,10 // position of quad #1
20,20, 20,20, 20,20, 20,20, 20,20, 20,20 // position of quad #2
30,30, 30,30, 30,30, 30,30, 30,30, 30,30 // position of quad #3
40,40, 40,40, 40,40, 40,40, 40,40, 40,40 // position of quad #4
```

Then in the vertex shader something like:

```
attribute vec2 aVert;
attribute vec2 aPos;

uniform float uSize;

void main() {
  vec2 realVertexPosition = aVert * uSize + aPos;
  gl_Position = toScreenSpaceMagic(realVertexPosition);
}
```

The thing that's weirding me out about this is how much data repetition there is here.

If I have 1000 quads, then I have identical vertex data repeated 1000 times. And the position of every quad is repeated 6 times.

So is there a way to reuse a small buffer and tell WebGL how it repeats? Like, for example, tell WebGL that a buffer 1000 times, which has the vertices of only one quad?

---

Here's how I make the verts:

```
// pointsToQuads returns a [number, number][] with 6 elements
// for each point, 3 points for each triangle in quad.
// Note how each quad has a `pos` (meaning the center) of [0,0].
const quads = pointsToQuads(
  layoutNodes.map(() => ({
    pos: [0, 0],
    size: { width: 1, height: 1 },
  })),
)

// calls gl.bufferData() with the flattened array of values.
this.buffers.quads.updateBuffer(quads)


// Fill a buffer of center positions for every vertex.
// dupeEntries() here changes clones each element at it's
// original index 6 times, one for each vertex of that quad.
// This duplicates the same point six times.
this.buffers.positions.updateBuffer(
  dupeEntries(
    layoutNodes.map((node) => node.position),
    6,
  ),
)

// Generate other buffers (UVs, vertex colors, etc)
```

Then renders with something like this, assuming 1000 quads:

```
  // Calls gl.useProgram()
  shaderPrograms.layoutPoints.use((shader) => {

    // Calls gl.vertexAttribPointer() for each attribute.
    shader.setAttributes({

      // here are the same six points cloned 1000 times.
      aVert: this.buffers.quads,

      aUV: this.buffers.uv,
      aIconUV: this.buffers.iconUv,
      aPos: this.buffers.positions,
      aColor: this.buffers.stateColors,
    })

    // Calls gl.uniform[1,2,3,4]f() for each uniform
    shader.setUniforms({ uSize: styles.pointsLayout.size })

    // One draw calls now renders all 1000 quads, so count here is 1000 * 6.
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.buffers.quads.count)
  })
```

But what I want is something like where there are only six coordinates in the `quads` buffer, but call still draw 1000 quads with one draw call.

Something like:

```
// only six points in `buffer`
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.glBuffer) 

// Repeat buffer 1000 times.
gl.vertexAttribPointer(attribute, 1000 * 6, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)

// Then one draw call
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 1000 * 6)
```

But this obviously doesn't work because there are not 6000 vertices in the buffer, only 6.

---

Lastly, you may be asking why? In part this is academic. This duplication of data has me questioning if this is the right approach. But secondly, this is a Expo application to be run on mobile devices, some of which have lower much lower memory limits. So shuffling around huge arrays of duplicated data seems quite wasteful.

Comment: Yes, you can (and should) absolutely do that! Can you show us the code where you are creating the quads and drawing?

Comment: Added more info that's closer to my actual code.

Comment: What you're looking for is [instanced rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ANGLE_instanced_arrays), however your current approach might turn out to be faster in rendering performance.